# SQLZOO SELECT from nobel #14

Tags: sql, select

I don't know how to order the names after I sorted out the subject physics and chemistry!

> Question: The expression subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') can be
>   used as a value - it will be 0 or 1.
>
> Show the 1984 winners and subject ordered by subject and winner name;
>   but list Chemistry and Physics last.

```
SELECT winner, subject, subject IN('Physics', 'Chemistry')
FROM nobel
WHERE yr=1984
ORDER BY CASE
 WHEN subject IN ('Physics', 'Chemistry') = 0 THEN subject IN ('Physics', 'Chemistry')
 WHEN subject IN ('Physics', 'Chemistry') =  THEN winner
 ELSE winner 
End
```

url to problem for more details http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial

Answer (score 7):

I have tried in SQLZOO and following SQL gives correct result.

```
SELECT winner, subject
FROM nobel
WHERE yr=1984
ORDER BY subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry'), subject, winner
```

Comment: The reason SQLzoo allows this is probably due to bad conformance with the ANSI standard in the underlying database....

Comment: I use the same statement, but SQLZOO returns "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'".

Comment: @fish-404 In the top right of the page there is a settings icon in that change SQL engine to MYSQL it will work. These solutions won't work with Microsoft SQL engine.

Comment: @AllenJohnson Thankyou, it works!  The question guide in SQLZOO use this solution but not hint about the engine make people confused.

Answer (score 2):

As @AllenJohnson pointed, this caused by SQL Engine setting.

SQLZOO use the expression in its question guide, but dosen't point the SQL Engine will affect the syntax is correct or not.

> The expression subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') can be used as a value - it will be 0 or 1.

If you choose your SQLZOO SQL Engine as MySQL, you can use:

```sql
select 
    winner
    , subject
from nobel
where yr=1984
order by 
    subject in ('Physics','Chemistry')
    , subject
    , winner
```

If you choose your SQLZOO SQL Engine as Microsoft SQL, you can use:

```sql
select
    winner
    , subject
from nobel
where yr = 1984
order by
    case
        when subject in ('Physics', 'Chemistry') then 1
        else 0
    end
    , subject
    , winner
```

Answer (score 1):

The `in` operator can't be used in the select as you did, but you were on the right path using a case expression in the `order by` clause. What you want is this:

```
SELECT 
  winner, subject
FROM 
  nobel
WHERE 
  yr = 1984
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
  subject, 
  winner
```

As the problem states `IN ('Physics','Chemistry')` will evaluate to 1 or 0 so it can be used instead on the full case expression in some databases; though it's not conformant with standard ANSI SQL. MySQL will allow it I believe, but for example MS SQL will not.

Comment: It can be simplified by just using the IN expr.

Comment: @DylanSu I don't think it can in the SQL standard, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I understand. MySQL sometimes does some extension. Here it works.

Comment: @DylanSu Indeed it does. But in my opinion it's bad practice to teach non-standard extensions, and certainly without mentioning that it is. Bad on SQLZoo.

Answer (score 1):

```
select winner, subject
from nobel
where yr = '1984'
order by ( case subject
           when 'Chemistry' then 1
           when 'Physics'   then 2
           else 0
           end), subject, winner
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        winner, 
        subject
 FROM 
        nobel
 WHERE 
        yr=1984
 ORDER BY 
        subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry'),
        subject,
        winner
```

Answer (score -1):

```
## Heading ##SELECT *
From (Select Top (Select count(winner) from nobel where yr = 1984 AND subject NOT IN ('Chemistry', 'Physics')) winner, subject
    FROM nobel
    WHERE yr=1984 AND subject NOT IN ('Chemistry', 'Physics')
    Order By subject, winner) AS zero
UNION
Select *
From (Select TOP (Select count(winner) from nobel where yr = 1984 AND subject IN ('Chemistry', 'Physics')) winner, subject
    From nobel
    Where yr = 1984 AND subject IN ('Chemistry', 'Physics')
    Order By subject, winner) AS one
```

it shows result but not correct answer.